# How to redirect all request to root directory on IIS server?

Tags: iis

I have a directory that looks like this:

```
 /root
    /home
    /about
    index.html
```

My example.com domain points to my root directory and I want to configure all requests like example.com/home or example.com/about to stay in the root directory and return the index.html.

Answer (score 0):

This rule will **rewrite all** (including css,js, and other resources) non-homepage requests to your index.html on the root.

```
<rule name="rewrite to index" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^$" negate="true" />
     <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
</rule>
```